# ASP.NET Gridview, rows do not show if rows are less then page size

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I seem to be running into an issue where my Grid-view doesn't display any rows when the number of items is less the page size (in this case 10), I'm using the object data source and at times it can return 1 or 7 for the number of items function call, which cause the grid view to not display anything at all. If I change the page size to 1 or 7 then the results will show. Anyone else run into this issue, any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Please post here the aspx tag of the GridView and also eventually the server side code you use for the data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your code and post some code as well. It's 99.9% certain that it's a problem with your code - you have bug in your code somewhere, step through it.

Did you customize the paging ?

Comment: yea it was my code..... in a scenerio where the results i got back where less then 10, i skipped adding there rows to the datatable that got returned.